# adding unique values in db and ignoring space

Tags: sql, vb.net

i have a combo box which is populated by a database table.i have a add button. On add button user is prompt to enter a unique name 
i check this unique name if it is present in db. If its not present i add the name to combobox. But the problrm is db treats "AB" and "A B"
as different names. how can i over come this problem i dnt want the user to add "AB" or "A B" again if once "AB" is added.

```
Public Function CheckGridNames(ByVal gridname As String) As Boolean
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Try
        Dim connection As New OleDbConnection
        connection.ConnectionString = GetConnectionStringForAdmin()
        connection.Open()
        If (ConnectionState.Open) Then
            Dim objCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
            objCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
            objCommand.CommandText = String.Format("select * from MultiSheetGrid where [GRID_NAME]='{0}'", gridname)
            objCommand.Connection = connection
            Using Adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(objCommand.CommandText.ToString(), connection.ConnectionString.ToString())
                Adapter.Fill(dt)
            End Using
            connection.Close()

            If (dt.Rows.Count > 0) Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MDIEventLog.WriteEntry("DrawingGridDB|ReadGridNames" & ex.Message, Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error)
    End Try
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
objCommand.CommandText = String.Format("select * from MultiSheetGrid where ltrim(rtrim(REPLACE([GRID_NAME],' ','')))='{0}'", gridname.Trim().Replace(" ",string.Empty))
```

Answer (score 0):

You handle that by making some logic in your code which handles the specific business rules you have.

One way would be to store a 'comparison' key - for example if you don't want spaces to be used in comparison key, then store the values into a column where you've stripped spaces.
So you could make a "CompareValue" where you store AB into, and then when you want to compare the input A B you remove spaces and compare against CompareValue. Then you can have A B and AB resolve to the same.

Others use a hashing function to return a key and then store the hash instead of just the string value.

But basically - it's business rules, so it can differ wildly from case to case.